# prop() is not working properly in jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my code

```
var options=$('#id').find(':selected'); 

$.each(options, function(key, value) {
    this.prop('selected', false));
});
```

How to make the `option` selected false. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `options.prop('selected', false)` no need of `each` and if your element is `select` just use `$('#id').val('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)`. `prop()` is jQuery function. You cannot use it directly on javascript object. `$(this)` is the `this` object wrapped in jQuery. So, you can call jQuery methods on it.

Also, remove the extra `)` of `prop`.

```
$(this).prop('selected', false);
```

To unseelect all the elements(without `each`):

```
$('#id :selected').prop('selected', false);
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 1):

No need of any `each` loop regarding your posted code. Just use:

```
var options = $('#id').find(':selected').prop('selected', false);
```